# How Can an app take a screenshot while running in the background and save it on a server

Tags: android

is it possible to make my App take a screenshot by code .. and then save it on server 
  (I'm using parse as a backend Server)

Comment: If it's possible for your code to run while the app is in the background, a method to capture the screenshot and send it to your server can get the job done. The problematic part is **knowing** whether your app is in the background or not.

Comment: You are welcome to use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+, with user approval, to take screenshots.

Comment: I need more detailed answer please  @CommonsWare